# Mongo db sha 1 to sha256

Tags: c#, mongodb, sha256

I would like to move my authentication over from sha-1 to sha 256, however, even though I've created a hasher I get an error stating that its unable to authenticate using sha1. There is no reference in the code to this old mechanism and I've already created a sha256 user in my mongo DB. Which means it is being defaulted to the old version somehow. Looking at the code I get warnings stating that MongoClientSettings is obsolete but browsing the web I don't see an alternative unless I'm meant to be using a connection string instead? The documentation for mongo client still accepts a mongoClientSettings in the constructor? Im using MongoDB version 4.10 and mongocsharpdriver 2.10

```
public static MongoClientSettings PrepareMongoSettings(string dbName)
    {
        MongoClientSettings mongoSettings = new MongoClientSettings();
        mongoSettings.Server = new MongoServerAddress(Host, Port);
        mongoSettings.ConnectionMode = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MongoUsername))
        {
            List<MongoCredential> mongoCredentials = new List<MongoCredential>();
            MongoCredential mongoCred = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("admin", MongoUsername, MongoPassword);
            mongoCredentials.Add(mongoCred);
            mongoSettings.Credentials = mongoCredentials;
        }

        return mongoSettings;
    }
```

The hasher that I have created is pretty basic the password should get hashed for before this code it is entered into the DB.

```
public static class HasherSha256
{
    public static byte[] GetPasswordHash(string username, string password)
    {
        // get salted byte[] buffer, containing username, password and some (constant) salt
        byte[] buffer;
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write("MyDB");
            writer.Write(username);
            writer.Write(password);
            writer.Flush();

            buffer = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return ComputeSha256Hash(buffer);
    }

    static byte[] ComputeSha256Hash(byte[] rawData)
    {
        using (SHA256 sHA256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            return sHA256.ComputeHash(rawData);

        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any documentation that says `MongoClientSettings` is obsolete. It is very much an available feature for connecting to MongoDB. [See Documentation here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClientSettings.htm). `Credentials` was deprecated but replaced with `Credential` which takes only one credential.. not an array.

```
new MongoClientSettings()
{
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.ReplicaSet,
    Credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("admin", Username, Password),
    ReplicaSetName = "ReplicaSetName",
    Servers =  new List<MongoServerAddress>(){new MongoServerAddress("server", 27017), new MongoServerAddress("server2", 27017)}.ToArray(),
    ApplicationName = "AppName",
}
```

Comment: Hi @jawad, I'm using mongo CSharp driver 2.10. Just to confirm i won't have to force it to use sha 256?  How will mongo know what encryption type to use?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo DB 4.0 has support for SCRAM-SHA-256. Salted Challenge Response Authentication Mechanism (SCRAM-SHA-256) uses SHA-256 hashing function.

The easiest way to enable it is by adding it to the connecting string. For example:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://user1:pwd1@host1/?authSource=db1&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256");
```

[Check out the official documentation here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/driver/tutorials/authentication/)