# Passing authenticationDatabase parameter to mongo C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Following command line works for me:

```
mongo -u myUsername -p myPassword --authenticationDatabase myAuthDb
use myDb
db.myCollection.find({})
```

However I cannot seem to authenticate properly from C#. My code:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@localhost:27017/myAuthDb";
var mongoSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
var mongoClient = new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient(mongoSettings);
mongoClient.GetDatabase("myDb").GetCollection("myCollection").FindAsync(...);
```

Throws the following exception:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.
 ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed: Authentication failed..
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(IConnection connection, ConnectionDescription description, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.GetChannelAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadContext.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadContext.CreateAsync(IReadBinding binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IReadBinding binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellat
ionToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
...
```

I'm assuming the issue is with the authenticationDatabase since when I'm using the `admin` db as follows, everything works fine.

```
mongo -u root -p rootPassword
use myDb
db.myCollection.find({})
```

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://root:rootPassword@localhost:27017";
var mongoSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
var mongoClient = new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient(mongoSettings);
mongoClient.GetDatabase("myDb").GetCollection("myCollection").FindAsync(...);
```

I'm using recent versions.

Mongo version 4.2

Mongo C# driver version 2.10.2

Comment: what version of MongoDB and c# driver are you using ?

Comment: @Jawad thanks, edited

Comment: See if [this solves your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60340738/1390548). Shows you how to set up authentication with adminDB with CreateCredential

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this connection string:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@localhost:27017/myDb?authSource=myAuthDb";
```

or without initial Database:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@localhost:27017?authSource=myAuthDb";
```

The [Connection String URI Format documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html) is not 100% clear regarding `authSource`

Comment: I know for sure that `authenticationDatabase` works in the URI. Not positive about `authSource`.

Comment: `authenticationDatabase` is used as option for starting the mongo shell. For URI connection string it is `authSource`

Comment: Interesting, my auth has been working for 5 years with `authenticationDatabase`. After digging in, it seems that admin is used if you don't specify a default db. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCredential.cs#L516 TIL